# Cannot get local IP address in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ip-address

I'm create a website using ReactJS and I want get my local IP address. I've tried few ways to do that but I was confused with result.

First, I use module on `npm` is [`local-ip-url`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-ip-url), then use `localIpUrl()` to get my ip address and display with `console.log()`. If i use a terminal to run this `.js` file (eg: `node index.js`), it print exact result i want (`192.168.x.x`). But if i use browser to see console log, it shows a different result `127.0.0.0`.

I've tried another ways, create my own function:

```
const os = require('os');

function getAvailableIp() {
    let ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
    let result = {};
    for (let ifname in ifaces) {
        ifaces[ifname].forEach(function (iface) {
            if ('IPv4' !== iface.family || iface.internal !== false) return;
            result[ifname] = iface.address;

        });
    };
    return result;
}

function getIp() {
    let ips = getAvailableIp();
    return ips.WiFi || 'localhost';
}
```

Same like above, when I ran code in terminal, it showed perfect result. But on browser, function `os.networkInterfaces()` return a empty object `{}`(It has a property is **proto**, i think it doesn't cause problem). So, it always return `localhost`.

[image: Result]

Anyone can explain?

Comment: Hi, just want to check that have you solved it? I got the same issue

Comment: No, I haven't. It seems impossible to do that with reactJS

Comment: My bet that os.networkInterfaces() is intended to work on server side. I just had the exact same problem on my React app, and had to move the IP retrieval from React the my nodejs server (which feeds React) to get the computer IP address. Same goes for local-ip-url: run on client-side, it returns 127.0.0.0, local browser IP.